# GAE GO Http call with Delete method returning 403 (Access Denied)

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am having Google App Engine Go application. Recently I have noticed all HTTP DELETE calls are failing with 403 and an html page returned saying "Access Denied". The call is not going to the actual application the error seems to be returned by App Engine.

No error found in GAE logs.

This seems to be recent security changes in GAE causing this. But I don't find a way to enable DELETE method. All other methods GET, POST and PUT are working without any issue. I have searched GAE help but not able to find any information related to this issue.

Any idea how to enable DELETE method?

To make simpler I have created new sample app with following code. For any http call to "/" it returns "test"(by default it should return 200 OK).

```
package hello

import (
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
)

func init() {
   http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprint(w, "Test")
}
```

Now If call GET, PUT and POST it is successfully returning test with 200.
For DELETE it is returning following html text with http error code 403.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
 Description: You are not allowed to access the document you  requested.
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>
```

For local server DELETE method working fine and returning 200 OK with "test"

Comment: Can you also post the code that handles the DELETE request?

Comment: The request is not logged in appengine request log. But POST, PUT & GET requests are logged.

Comment: I'd recommend looking for some top level AppEngine settings that might be doing some pre-filtering. The request is getting blocked before it goes to your Go code.

Comment: I don't find any settings related to pre-filtering.

Comment: I have verified today without changing any code. The HTTP delete method is working without any issues. I don't find any data about this problem else where.